# Get the primary SMTP email address of current Azure AD user from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm writing a PowerShell script where I need the email address of the currently logged on user on a Azure AD joined computer.

`$Env:Username` might be the starting point but on its own, it's not enough. Specifically, one of the users got married, so her name changed from `Claire Smith` to `Claire Jones` but `$Env:Username` is still `clairesmith` (and her user profile has the old name). There must be some mapping going on under the hood.

The script needs to be able to run as a normal user and I don't want to prompt for credentials.

Any ideas?

Comment: **Why** is the `USERNAME` environment variable set to their given name instead of some standard ID?

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Identity claire.smith -Properties ProxyAddresses | select -ExpandProperty ProxyAddresses | ? {$_ -clike "SMTP:*"}` Try this, you will be able to get the SMTP Email adress

Comment: There is no mapping under the hood when a users `displayName` or `sn` is changed. The `sAMAccountnName` will remain the same (same goes for `objectSid`, `objectGUID` etc). So use the method  @HariHaran gave, but perhaps extend it to get the `DisplayName` property too.